# SublimeText highlighting for plain text

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting

Sublime has highlighting plugins for almost any language, however 
often i use raw text format to write down some ongoing notes.

When the content gets big enough it is useful to have some highlighting,
one option is to use some programming language highlighting but it easily gets confused since its not really a code...

I remember there was a plugin that was basically finding top most frequent words, and highlighting them with different colors like a universal highlighting... it was naturally providing good highlighting even for code, since many keywords or variable names would turn out to be top repeated ones... Unfortunately i cannot find it now, no matter how i search.

Does anyone know this plugin or have some recommendation for plain text highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I use raw text format to write down some ongoing notes**
>
> **Does anyone ... have some recommendation for plain text highlighting?**

If was using Sublime Text for plain text notes, I would use the available support for plain text markup such as Markdown. There is [Sublime Text support for highlighting Markdown](https://www.google.com/search?q=sublime+text+markdown+highlighting).